# React error: Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have the following code.

```
class InlineEditField extends Component {
render() {
...
return (
      <Row>
        <Column xs={3}>
          <b>
            <FormattedMessage id={`account.order.${label}`} defaultMessage="Order label" />
          </b>
        </Column>
      </row>
...
)
}
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: /opt/lampp/htdocs/authnt/my-account/src/components/InlineEditField.js: [React Intl] Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction.
  45 |         <Column xs={3}>
  46 |           <b>
> 47 |             <FormattedMessage id={`account.order.${label}`} defaultMessage="Order label" />
     |                                   ^
  48 |           </b>
  49 |         </Column>
```

I am new in React and implementing this for the very first time. Also looked in other stack answers but ouldn't get it to work.